# Ideal structure of a connection pool in tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, tomcat7

Look at my question arises in the following, whenever I want to access my database using a connection pool is always necessary to call the Init method in a servlet to retrieve the connection, for me this is a problem, I have been reviewing several questions here on the page.

My idea is to call in my first servlet init and Connection send the session to make changes to my database without having to be calling the init method, but it comes my question, where should I close my connection.

I tried to find an ideal structure of a connection pool to solve this problem.

My init method contains the following

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    Context ctx;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        sourceDb = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Practica5");

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And I go to session in :

```
synchronized (sourceDb) {
    con = sourceDb.getConnection();
}
if (con == null) {
    throw new ServletException("Problemas con la conexion");
}
request.getSession().setAttribute("con",con);
```

Answer (score 0):

sharing the database connection in session would be troublesome at any moment...
i feel that it might cause serialization issue during execution...

if the requirement is to use single connection object among the session then it is better to return the connection object to the pool and get it again in another servlet...

in this case we are ensuring that the connection object is maintained among the servlets through the data source

Comment: Then would have to be placed in each servlet the init method?, There will be a way to separate them?

Comment: need not to do that... initialize in one init() method and make that class to load first... it works...

Comment: Then when I initialize the servlet init my first then I can use my connecion for the following servlets?

Comment: As would get the connection to the other servlets, should set the first servlet?